# How to save two relation entities in Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm doing a user registration. I have two entities: User, UserCredential

```
#[Entity, Table(name: 'user')]
#[HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class UserEntity implements JsonSerializable
{
    const INACTIVE = 0;
    const ACTIVE = 1;
    const BLOCKED = 2;
    const IS_DELETED_NO = 0;
    const IS_DELETED_YES = 1;

    #[Id, Column(type: Types::INTEGER), GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    private int $id;

    #[Column(name: 'role_id', type: Types::INTEGER, length: 11, options: ['default' => 0])]
    private int $roleId;

    #[Column(name: 'email', type: Types::STRING, length: 255, unique: true, nullable: false)]
    private string $email;

    #[Column(name: 'status', type: Types::SMALLINT, options: ['default' => self::INACTIVE])]
    private int $status = self::INACTIVE;

    #[Column(name: 'created_at', type: Types::INTEGER, length: 11)]
    private int $createdAt;

    #[Column(name: 'updated_at', type: Types::INTEGER, length: 11)]
    private int $updatedAt;

    #[Column(name: 'is_deleted', type: Types::SMALLINT, options: ['default' => self::IS_DELETED_NO])]
    private int $isDeleted = self::IS_DELETED_NO;

    #[OneToOne(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: UserCredentialEntity::class)]
    private UserCredentialEntity $credential;
....




#[Entity, Table(name: 'user_credential')]
class UserCredentialEntity
{
    #[Id, Column(type: Types::INTEGER), GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    private int $id;

    #[Column(name: 'user_id', type: Types::INTEGER, length: 11)]
    private int $userId;

    #[Column(name: 'password_hash', type: Types::STRING, length: 255, nullable: false)]
    private string $passwordHash;

    #[Column(name: 'email_confirm_key', type: Types::STRING, length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $emailConfirmKey = null;


    #[OneToOne(targetEntity: UserEntity::class)]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private UserEntity $user;

    public function __construct(UserEntity $user, string $password)
    {
        //$this->userId = $user->getId();
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->passwordHash = $password;
    }
}


 public function createUser(string $email, string $password): User | Exception
    {
        $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $user = new User($email);
            $user->setRoleId(1);
            $this->em->persist($user);

            $userCredential = new UserCredentialEntity($user, 'password');

            $this->em->persist($userCredential);
            $this->em->flush();

            $this->em->getConnection()->commit();

            return $user;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
            $this->em->getConnection()->rollback();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

How to make the UserCredential entity be saved automatically with the required User id?

I'm getting an error:

"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you have two references to the User in the UserCredentials?

In the User entity

```
#[OneToOne(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: UserCredentialEntity::class)]
private UserCredentialEntity $credential;
```

In the UserCredentials entity

Remove the **$userId** in this class because you can already get it from the **$user**.

```
#[OneToOne(inversedBy: 'credential', targetEntity: UserEntity::class)]
private UserEntity $user;
```

Comment: Thanks! But, how can i save this entities? So that after creating User I can put password in UserEntity and save it with id from User

Comment: Do as I said in my answer. Remove the $userId from your UserCredentialEntity. 
( because you will be able to gather it with $userCredential->getUser()->getId() )

Once you have modified your code and put the relations I gave you, it should work with the code you have in your controller.

If this doesn't work, try to call the ->flush() method after the ->commit().

Don't forget to recheck the doctrine:migration:diff command and to remake the migration if necessary.

Comment: And I just noticed the error you're having is because you tell in your UserCredential class that user_id cannot be null (you don't have nullable: false). When you create your UserCredential object, you never set the $user_id, so doctrine won't persist it. 

You can simply set it to nullable or pass it in the constructor of your object.

Comment: It works! Thanks you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, which solution did you choose?

Don't forget to tag your question as solved.

Comment: i just remove private $user_id (the Doctrine automatically made the field user_id) and remove the relation OneToOne in User entity. Passed $user as an argument and everything worked :)

$userCredential = new UserCredential($user, $password);